# bool(false) when var_dump($json_array)

Tags: php, json, mysqli

I'm trying to retrieve an Array from a query, query is ok, I got a assoc_array, when I `var_dump()` said array everything is ok.

to that array after `json_enconde($assoc_array)`

However when I do a `var_dump($json_array)` I got a bool(false)

Normal assoc_array from query is:

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(4) { ["nombre"]=> string(13) "Raxo Pimienta" ["descripcion"]=> string(52) "Ternera en salsa a la pimienta acompa�ada de patatas" ["precio"]=> string(2) "14" ["id"]=> string(1) "1" } [1]=> array(4) { ["nombre"]=> string(14) "Ensalada Cesar" ["descripcion"]=> string(58) "Lechuga, bacon, crotones y salsa cesar con queso parmesano" ["precio"]=> string(1) "8" ["id"]=> string(1) "2" } }
```

Comment: `json_enconde($assoc_array)` you have a misspelling.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is not binary safe. there's lots of binary data that simply cannot be encoded to json. PHP strings, on the other hand, is completely binary safe, they can contain any sequence of bytes whatsoever (unlike json). your array probably contains a (php) string with a byte sequences that cannot be json-encoded. try to `var_dump(json_last_error_msg());`, it should state why the encoding failed. you could try to use the JSON_PARTIAL_OUTPUT_ON_ERROR flag, but you'd be better off locating the source of this json-incompatible data, and encode that to something json-safe. ps, just like php strings, base64 encoding is binary safe. when you find the source, you could encode that in base64, which can then be added to the json.

edit: the json-incompatible character is probably that weird character in the ["descripcion"]: `acompa�ada` - and suggests that you're having an encoding problem elsewhere. (are you using the utf8 charset when connecting to a sql db? is the db table using the utf8 collation? looks like there is an encoding mistake somewhere leading to a corruption of the "descripcion" string)

Answer (score -1):

Problem was a "ñ" character from DB data, no more.